# Regular Expressions in Using Pattern java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as below.

```
$Alarm:com.Alarm(a  ==  123 || (count  ==  12345 , time  matches  "24"))
```

whenever i encounter the above string i need to generate the following string.I mean i need to append the string "from Stream" as below.

```
$Alarm:com.Alarm(a  ==  123 || (count  ==  12345 , time  matches  "24")) from Stream.
```

I am currently using the following pattern to acheive the same in java.

```
Pattern eventPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.Alarm\\(.*?\\)");
```

But i am getting the following output.

```
$Alarm:com.Alarm(a  ==  123 || (count  ==  12345 , time  matches  "24") from Stream )
```

Please provide me some pointers to acheive the correct output.The regular expression should consider only the last paranthesis.

Comment: Can you show some code on how you are using your `eventPattern`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include parens matching in your Pattern. Something like the following:

```
Pattern eventPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.Alarm\\(([^\\(]*?|\\([^\\)]*?\\))*\\)");
```

Things up to and including the first open parens: `.*?\\.Alarm\\(`

Stuff outside any internal parens: `[^\\(]*?`

Internal parens pair: `\\([^\\)]*?\\)`

Match any number of stuff outside parens or within a parens pair: `([^\\(]*?|\\([^\\)]*?\\))*`

This [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) site is a great place to play with regexes to see what will work.

Comment: Which will effectively only work if the maximum level of nesting of brackets is known in advance. Regular expressions aren't Turing-complete...

Comment: Good point - poster needs to answer to what degree this is an issue

Comment: My requirment is irrespective of the number of parantesis[")"].The string needs to append to only after last closing paranthesis[")"].